How using multiple volatile fields can bring them into synchronization order?
The description of the following JCStress test:
    @JCStressTest
    @Outcome(id = {"0, 1", "1, 0", "1, 1"}, expect = ACCEPTABLE, desc = "Trivial under sequential consistency")
    @Outcome(id = "0, 0",                   expect = FORBIDDEN,  desc = "Violates sequential consistency")
    @State
    public static class VolatileDekker {
        volatile int x;
        volatile int y;

        @Actor
        public void actor1(II_Result r) {
            x = 1;
            r.r1 = y;
        }

        @Actor
        public void actor2(II_Result r) {
            y = 1;
            r.r2 = x;
        }
    }

says that:

Adding volatile to both $x and $y bring them together into
synchronization order, and thus require the results to be consistent
with the case when reads/writes form a total order.

as the explanation of why the outcome "0,0" is impossible. However, what is the reason regarding why x and y are brought together into synchronization order? Citing the "Java Concurrency In Practice"

When thread A writes to a volatile variable and subsequently
thread B reads that same variable, the values of all variables that were
visible to A prior to writing to the volatile variable become visible to B after
reading the volatile variable.

about the happens-before relationship I would assume that the compiler:

cannot reorder instructions which are before writing to a volatile field after it
cannot reorder instructions which are after reading a volatile field before it

making it possible for the compiler to:

possibly reorder instructions which are after writing to a volatile field before it
possibly reorder instructions which are before reading from a volatile field after it

thus resulting in the following code:
        @Actor
        public void actor1(II_Result r) {
            r.r1 = y;
            x = 1;
        }

        @Actor
        public void actor2(II_Result r) {
            r.r2 = x;
            y = 1;
        }

which could get the 0,0 outcome, but it seems that it is not possible.

I think you should explain more what you are trying to say here.  Can provide an example code trace of what you think is a legal access that allows the value (0,0) to be seen?  I don't have JCIP handy but there's likely some additional explanation beyond your short quote that explains more fully.  For the Java specification, it says that actions happen-before, and actions include both reads and writes.  Trying reading the spec and see how it squares with your understanding of JCIP.

I also think you're reading "both $x and $y bring them together into synchronization order" incorrectly.  There's no ordering here, it would depend on the order the test driver executes the method calls.  And we don't have that information here.  So I'm still uncertain exactly what order you think is going to be a problem or what you are asking, exactly.

@markspace: The spec says that "A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that field." That matches what the OP has quoted from JCIP, and also matches the OP's understanding of it.

@markspace I haven't found an explanation in the JCIP why would the 0,0 outcome be forbidden and this is why I asked the question as the JCStress clearly says that this is not possible when fields are volatile.

Your assumption is correct. It's theoretically possible to get (0,0) outcome. The test doesn't fail because the implementation doesn't do that reordering(or less likely it's possible but never happened when the test was run) but it's possible according to the specification. The jcstress is wrong, it's not common but mistakes can happen anywhere.
I don't have much to add, you provided the relevant quote from Java Concurrency In Practice, explained what the Java memory model does and does not guarantee and showed how (0,0) is possible in your question.

This does not actually answer the question, which is, How does adding volatile to the declarations of x and y make (0, 0) a forbidden outcome?

@SolomonSlow It doesn't, according to the specification it's a possible outcome, the test is wrong. I thought it's clear, added an explicit sentence to the answer saying that it's wrong.

OK, glad to hear it. I racked my brain, trying to find some reason why (0, 0) would be an impossible outcome, and I came up with nothing. But, the author of the stress test said, "FORBIDDEN...violates sequential consistency," and I figured that they must have known some some subtle rule about volatile that I hadn't yet heard of yet. Glad to hear that it's not actually any more complicated than what I already knew.

Reading a volatile object in Java doesn't guarantee that the read will show the object's current value, in any sense of the word.  To the contrary, it guarantees that the read won't reflect any changes to the value until the implementation can ensure that all all modifications of all other objects that occurred before the volatile object was written will be visible to the thread that read the volatile object.
Volatile writes and reads are often described as having "release" and "acquire" semantics.  The way I like to think of that is to recognize that if code which holds a lock writes some arbitrary object X and then releases the lock, it would need to ensure that X gets committed to memory before the lock was released.  If some other code acquires the lock and observes X, it would be required to ensure that the reported value of X was fetched from memory after the lock was acquired.  The scenario shown in the question would be analogous to code which releases a lock, then writes an object, reads another object, and then acquires a lock.  Since the write and read occur with no intervening actions involving the lock, there would be no obligation to ensure that the written value would be committed to memory before code tried to read the other value, nor that the value which was read was fetched from memory only after the other value had been written.
Note that if these were the only volatile-qualified actions that were performed by a program, it would be unlikely that the JVM would reorder things in problematic fashion.  If, however, the target platform was one which required explicit memory barriers to guarantee acquire/release semantics, memory barriers had a large associated time penalty, and the sequence of steps in the OP question was bracketed by a write and a read of things other than the fields used in this example, yielding an overall sequence: "write A / do stuff #1 / read X / do stuff #2 / write Y / do stuff #3 / read B", performing all of the volatile operations in sequence would rquire memory barriers around the first and third "do stuff", for a total of four memory barriers.  The Java specification, however, woul allow the requested sequence of operations to be realized as "write A / write Y / MEMORY BARRIER / do stuff #1, #2, and #3 / MEMORY BARRIER / read X / read B".  This would reduce the number of memory barriers from four to two, but if one thread executed everything before "do stuff #2" before the other thread did anything, and didn't run anything after that point until the other thread had done everything, the final reported result could be 0,0.

Can you add something here to explicitly address the question of whether "0, 0" is a legal outcome?

I added a concrete example of a sitaution where treating writes as only being release semantics, and reads as only having acquire semantics, could allow improved performance but yield what would otherwise seem to be an impossible sequence of events.

Re, "it guarantees that the read won't reflect any changes to the value until..." What you said is true, but it could be misunderstood. A newbie might think you were saying that if thread A writes some volatile x, then thread B will wait for that write when it tries to read x. But of course, what you really are saying is, *IF* thread A already has written to x before thread B tries to read it, then thread B may be forced to wait for other things that thread A has written before the read x operation can be completed.

@SolomonSlow: If thread A has writes X before thread B reads it and then some other things, thread B could either of two things: (1) Yield the new value of X, and ensure that reads of any variable A might have written before X will wait if needed until those values have made their way to the processor running thread B; (2) yield the old value of X, without waiting and arbitrarily yield old or new values for other things A wrote before X.  The only forbidden scenario would be yielding a new value of X without also yielding the new values for anything written before X.

@SolomonSlow: In practice, given a choice between hastening the propagation of earlier non-qualified writes, or delaying the propagation of volatile writes, implementations will generally favor the former when practical (and then hasten the performance of volatile-qualified writes as much as practical subject to the constraint that they lag behind earlier non-qualified writes), but as noted they may defer the proagation of values from volatile writes in some cases where that would improve overall throughput.

@SolomonSlow: I think it's important to recognize that the ordering guarantees associated with volatile-qualified accesses in Java are in stronger than those of C in ways that favor some common usage patterns, but are weaker than those of C in some other ways which are not necessarily intuitive.
